# SQL Modified Result Set Depending on Date Adding Pre Headers, etc

Tags: sql, sqlite

I know SQL, but am not heavy in SQL.  So, here is a question that I would want to know if it is possible and if so how.. (Group By?)

We have a table

```
Data   Date
1      JUN-1-2001
2      JUN-1-2001
3      JUN-2-2001
4      JUN-2-2001
5      JUN-3-2001
```

I would like to have the result set sorted by date with a "pre header" of the date, something like...

Target is SQLLite 3

```
Data    Date
0       JUN-1-2001
1       JUN-1-2001
2       JUN-1-2001
0       JUN-2-2001
3       JUN-2-2001
4       JUN-2-2001
0       JUN-3-2001
5       JUN-3-2001
```

Anyway, would appreciate the help on this one.  There is a reason for my madness.

Comment: _Why_ do you want to do this?  If this is for something like report headers, or similar formatting issues, you're better off doing that in the report program, **not** in the database.

Comment: I said on purpose that there is a reason for my madness.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
select data, date from mytable union all
select distinct 0 as data, date from mytable
order by 1, 2
```